# Convert XLSM to CSV limiting number of columns (range)

Tags: python, excel, csv, copy

I have an .xlsm (excel) file that I would like to read and copy to an .csv file instead. The first 15 columns have data on it and the last column of the Excel file as well, but I only want to copy data from the first 15 columns from the .xlsm to .csv. Is it possible? Right now this is what I have done:

```
import openpyxl as ox
import csv

wb = ox.load_workbook('C:/Quebras.xlsm')
ws = wb['Quebras']

c = csv.writer(open('C:/Quebras.csv', 'w'))
for r in ws.rows:
    c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r])
```

Comment: You only want the first 15 columns? Just use slicing: `c.writerow([cell.value for cell in r[:15]])`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to use `iter_rows()` to iterate over your required rows. This takes the `min_col` and `max_col` parameters. It can also just return a row of values by passing `values_only=True`.

For example:

```
import openpyxl as ox
import csv

wb = ox.load_workbook('Quebras.xlsm')
ws = wb['Quebras']

with open('Quebras.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=15, values_only=True):
        csv_output.writerow(row)
```

Adding `newline=''` should stop you getting extra blank lines in your CSV file.